# Thesis title pages

Tags: pdftex, titles

Does anyone of you ever experienced some difficulties in putting together a title page for a thesis? This seems super easy, but here I gave up... Any help or suggestions will be so greatly appreciated. I tried to create this following title page in latex, but constant errors just annoyed me.

[image]

```
\newcommand{\tbf}[1]{\text{\textbf{#1}}}
%title page
\thispagestyle{plain}
\centerline{Pretty Girls Secrets}.
\centerline{\textnormal{by}
\centerline{\textnormal{Pretty Girl Flirty}
\par\vspace*{.25\textheight}{\centering A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of}
\centerline{\textnormal{ Doctor of Philosophy }
\centerline{\textnormal{in}
\centerline{\textnormal{Flits Science}
\par\vspace*{.55\textheight}{\centering Department of Flirty Girls and Boys Science}
\centerline{\textnormal{ Flirt University}
\:\textcopyright  Pretty Girl Flirty, 2015
```

Another issue with this:
I have dots (..............)- where the examiners should put their signatures, but I would like to have straight lines instead of dots. Thanks. Sally.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show a minimal working document that produces this output, not just a screenshot, leaving guess-work to users here. (I've deleted the totally irrelevant [tag:latex3] as well)

Comment: Sure. This is what I have tried so far:..

Comment: No, add this to the post above, not as a comment

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simple title page by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,a4wide}

\begin{document}



\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
Pretty Girls Secrets \\
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
by \\
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
Pretty Girl Flirty \\
\vspace{3.5cm}
A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \\
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
Doctor of Philosophy  \\ 
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
in \\ 
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
Flirt Science \\
\vspace{2cm}
Examined and approved on\\
\vspace{3mm}
\rule{.2\textwidth}{.5pt}\\
\vspace{3mm}
by the following examiner:\\
\vspace{5mm}
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5pt}\\
Dr Xxxxx Xxxx (supervisor)\\




\vspace{2cm}
Department of Flirty Girls and Boys Science \\
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
Flirt University \\
\vspace{6cm}
\: \textcopyright  Pretty Girl Flirty, 2015
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.

Here is my title page.

[image]